# After Windows 10 upgrade I have to enter my WIFI password for every startup

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

Until I upgraded to Windows 10, everything was working fine.
Now I have to enter my WIFI data (SSID and password for a hidden network) each time I start the computer.

Why, how do I find out what is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Edit:
I just noticed that the wifi connection gets synchronized to another computer running windows 8.1 at another location out of reach of the wifi network. This is to be expected because of the synchronization settings.